# GDI+ text has a black edge

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+

I'm clearing an image with a transparent color (120 alpha) and then drawing a string onto it with a gradient, and then drawing that image onto a larger image but the text has blackish edge to it instead of being nice and smooth like it should be. The text looks fine if the background is drawn with 255 alpha.

120 Alpha: [Image](http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/4581/currentt.png)

255 Alpha: [Image](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/6761/expected.png)

As you can see, the text is much easier to read with the background fully opaque

Note: the green dot is my cursor

Edit: `gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;`  removes the black edges but it's blurry, I'll try some other combinations of graphics settings and see how this goes.

Edit: `gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;`  Looks much better, although the A's in the Arial font look a little funky

Comment: The newer fonts like Segoe UI play much better with antialiasing.

Comment: Your 255 image doesn't load. (png error)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour. You must change your drawing order to get it right.

Since you draw the text onto a semi-transparent surface its anti-aliasing pixels will be semi-transparent, too, but somwehre in-between the text color and the background of the first image.

Now, if you draw the result onto another image you will have uniform transparent pixels where no text is, no transparency where text is and varying tranparencies **and** colors for the antialiasing pixels.

Note that those will have various colors as the antialiasing tries to spread color diferences as well as differences in brightness.

Either write on a non-transparent surface or delay the writing to the end. (Or turn off all anti-aliasing. But that's not nice.)